# python wikipedia package changing input

Tags: python, wikipedia

I'm running a script to get pages related to a word using python (pip3 install wikipedia). I enter a word to search, let's say the word is "cat". I send that to the code below, but the wikipedia code changes it to "hat" and returns pages related to "hat". It does this with any word I search for (ie: "bear" becomes "beard". "dog" becomes "do", etc...)

```
wikipedia_page_name = "cat"
print("Original: ", wikipedia_page_name)
myString = wikipedia.page(wikipedia_page_name)
print("Returned: ", myString)
```

Here is what I get back:

```
Original:  cat
Returned:  <WikipediaPage 'Hat'>
```

My steps to use this were to install wikipedia "pip3 install wikipedia" and then import it "import wikipedia". That's it! I've tried uninstalling and then reinstalling, but I get the same results.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to work with the page `<WikipediaPage 'Cat'>`, please try to set `auto_suggest` to False as `suggest` can be pretty bad at finding the right page:

```
import wikipedia

wikipedia_page_name = "cat"
print("Original: ", wikipedia_page_name)
myString = wikipedia.page(wikipedia_page_name, pageid=None, auto_suggest=False)
print("Returned: ", myString)
```

Output:

```
Original:  cat
Returned:  <WikipediaPage 'Cat'>
```

If you want to find titles, use `search` instead:

```
import wikipedia

wikipedia_page_name = "cat"
searches = wikipedia.search(wikipedia_page_name)
print(searches)
```

Output:

```
['Cat', 'Cat (disambiguation)', 'Keyboard Cat', 'Calico cat', 'Pussy Cat Pussy Cat', 'Felidae', "Schrödinger's cat", 'Tabby cat', 'Bengal cat', 'Sphynx cat']
```

You can use both together to make sure you get the right page from a String, as such:

```
import wikipedia

wikipedia_page_name = "cat"
searches = wikipedia.search(wikipedia_page_name)
if searches:
    my_page = wikipedia.page(searches[0], pageid=None, auto_suggest=False)
    print(my_page)
else:
    print("No page found for the String", wikipedia_page_name)
```

Output:

```
<WikipediaPage 'Cat'>
```